# awk cutting off when printing fields

Tags: bash, awk

I've searched endlessly and can't find anything to address what seems like is a really simple problem.

I have the following line that reads in a csv file and just uses the fields to create a new string.

The input is a simple 2-column set of integers:

```
1234,1
5678,2
1357,5
2468,4
```

The expected output for each should be something like "rating should be 1 and id should be 1234" for each line.

```
awk -F "," '{print "rating should be "$2" and id should be "$1}' $1 >> $FILENAME
```

But this is the output I get:

```
 and id should be 635277
 and id should be 29894
 and id should be 576076
```

I thought this was a case of the simplest string concatenation, but I'm totally new to awk, so I may very well be missing something obvious. How can I get this to print the string I want?

Comment: @Inian Sure, sorry. Added the extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your awk script which is fine as-is. Your input file contains control-Ms, use dos2unix or similar to remove them.

Comment: Thanks, I've heard of line endings being an issue. I'll verify this when I'm back on my work machine and switch the accepted answer to this if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

Recommend using [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) to print quoted strings, which is `POSIX` compatible and available across platforms.

```
awk -F"," '{printf "rating should be %d and id should be %s\n", $2,$1}' input-file
rating should be 1 and id should be 1234
rating should be 2 and id should be 5678
rating should be 5 and id should be 1357
rating should be 4 and id should be 2468
```

From your `print` example fixing your unterminated double-quote string, solved the issue for me as

```
awk -F "," '{print "rating should be "$2" and id should be "$1""}' input-file
rating should be 1 and id should be 1234
rating should be 2 and id should be 5678
rating should be 5 and id should be 1357
rating should be 4 and id should be 2468
```

Comment: Worked, thank you, but do you know why I was getting the cut off output with print?

Comment: @ssb: Well you had an unbalanced double-quote for a start! `printf` was my first idea when it comes to printing custom strings,

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that I needed to add double quotes to the end of it.

Comment: @ssb: It is basically the entire `print` within double-quotes and separately for `$1` and `$2` for expanding their value.

Comment: The only reason that is "solving" the problem is that the `printf "%d"` is converting the string `$2<control-M>` to the number `$2`. If you tried printing it as a string with `%s` the problem would still exist because the problem is trailing control-Ms in the input, not the output printing.

Comment: @ssb you absolutely did NOT need to add double quotes to the end of it, that is doing nothing in this case (it's only use is to force a string comparison when the items being compared look like numbers).